# Inserted figure is appearing later than it should in when compiled to pdf

Tags: graphics, floats, line-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

I have two sections in my document: `sectionA` and `sectionB`. The code for the document is something like this:

```
\begin{document}
\section{sectionA}

    some text

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{pic.ps}
        \caption{caption}
    \end{figure}

    some more text

\section{sectionB}

    even more text

\end{document}
```

However, `sectionB` is showing BEFORE the figure is displayed. In practice `sectionA` contains more text and is almost a full page, so I'm guessing LaTeX is placing the figure on the other page, seeing some empty space after `sectionA` and placing `sectionB` there.

How can I fix this? I would rather have `B` start after my figure, regardless of its size.

I've already tried `\begin{figure}[h!]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeins package http://ctan.org/pkg/placeins defines a `\FloatBarrier` command that keeps floats within sections. (It avoids forcing a `\clearpage` if possible.)

As noted by @RoelofSpijker in comments, if you use `[section]` option when loading the package, it automatically adds a barrier to each section.

Comment: perhaps add that you can load the package with the `section` option to solve this specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

`\clearpage` places all as-yet unplaced floats (including figures).